# Finitely Presented Modules and Exact Sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, projective-module

I came across this passage in Rotman's *Advanced Modern Algebra*:

> If $M$ is finitely presented, there is a short exact sequence
>
> $\begin{equation*}0 \rightarrow K \rightarrow F \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0,\end{equation*}$
>
> where $F$ is free and both $K$ and $F$ are finitely generated. Equivalently, $M$ is finitely presented if there is an exact sequence
>
> $\begin{equation*}F' \rightarrow F \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0,\end{equation*}$
>
> where both $F'$ and $F$ are finitely generated free modules (just map a finitely generated free module onto $K$).

It's not obvious to me why the second statement must be true. Is it really trivial enough to just claim in passing? Any insight would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It is obvious once you know that a module is finitely generated iff it is a quotient of a finitely generated free module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is equivalent.  If $K$ is finitely generated then there is a generating set $k_1, \ldots, k_n$.  Let $F'$ be free of rank $n$ and map $F' \to K$ by sending the generators of $F'$ to $k_1, \ldots, k_n$.  Then the map $F' \to F$ is the composition $F' \to K \to F$.

Conversely if you have $\phi\colon F' \to F$ then define $K = F'/\ker\phi$.  The module $K$ is finitely generated (use the generators of $F'$) and $\phi$ induces an injective map $K \to F$.

So basically the difference between a SES $0 \to K \to F \to M \to 0$ and a two step free resolution $F' \to F \to M \to 0$ is whether or not you've encoded the relations between the generators in the map $F' \to F$ or in the module $K$.